# clues, advices about how to decode a packet

Tags: audio, udp, protocols, reverse-engineering, network-protocols

I received a gift last year which is a Sony CMT700Ni audio station, wifi capable. It is also capable of a airplay-like feature which is called "PartyStreaming". I'm currently digging inside, explore it so maybe i could end having my own "PartyStreaming"-capable device and have AirPlay-like feature for free (the challenge is also very interesting)

PartyStreaming is a SOAP based service which is very easy to understand. There is 4 main functions divided in 2 groups : server-side and client-side. The 2 functions in each group represents starting a connexion with the other side or ending it (start/stop for server, join/leave for client)

Actually i've gone far since i'm now able to access the audio data that the server - the audio station - is spreading over the network. It seems like, after having joined the server with the soap method, the client has to send a UDP packet to the server on port 3975. When received, the server answers back by sending packets to the client on that same port, for 30s.

After looking at about a hundred of those, i figured out that a typical packet is 1024 bytes long, in which there is a header of 64 bytes, a fill of 64 bytes of 0, then a 896 bytes of sound data.

I have now the data, but it looks like a bunch of bytes written randomly. There's no codec info, no structure, no "chunck format" (like in wave files). I can't find any good documentation about the protocol or any "PartyStreaming" related technical stuff.

My question is : **"Hey StackOverflow, any advices ? any clues ? should i give up or maybe you have an idea i can test ?"**

---

Things that coud be usefull :

- Notes on the subject : http://pastebin.com/pp8aRQrR
- Dump of packets without headers : http://cl.ly/430H2i001K3R
- Dump of packets with headers and some formatting to read them : http://cl.ly/2i2F2c3E3W3C

---

Things i'm about to test now :

- Capture UDP packets as client, then start a server and send that data to my audio station to see if it can read it ; maybe there's a server-side encryption, if so, i'm stuck
- Build a 1kHz file, and play it on the audio station ; capture packets and watch its bytes, maybe compare with the same file encoded with many codec to find a pattern...

Comment: what programming language do you use?

Comment: i used python for quick development but i can use anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your bitrate is quite high, the data might be uncompressed. If that's the case, your data bytes are not really random - at least they are not uniformly distributed.

Try reconstructing samples (i.e. read signed ints) at different resolutions (8 bits, 16 bits, maybe something exotic in between). Do that on many packets, compute and display histograms (for 8 bit: count how many -128, how many -126 ... how many 127).

You should gather at least 100 samples per possible value (say for 8 bit: 12,800 samples) to have a good statistics. Then look at your histogram. If it's flat and all values have about the same number of occurrences then it's compressed/encrypted or you picked the wrong bits per sample. If some values have noticeably more or less occurrences than other: bingo it's uncompressed sound samples!

If you get flat histograms for all bits per sample, it becomes harder. You may try dumping say 100kb of data to a file and running it though linux/unix `file` command and see if it identify the format. It might recognize compression. Then you'll have to uncompress and repeat the whole process with the uncompressed stream: analyze histograms and run through `file`.

Also try running it through vlc, mplayer, ffplay which tap into rich libraries such as ffmpeg and might recognize the stream or give you useful messages in the debug output.

Anyway, if it's encrypted you're screwed... Or at least I doubt the effort is worth it;)

Comment: I already tried vlc with the biggest dump of data (first cloudlyapp link in the question) without success. A friend of mine just opened it in Audacity and played it. He said to me that it looks a bit slow in 32khz 16b stereo so he was thinking of ADPCM but since he didn't have any reference he could be wrong...

Comment: Try ffmpeg, with -f s16le -ar 44.1k -ac 2 [explained](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/audio%20types). Also if you're comfortable with it, you can output it problematically - since you mentioned python try [pyo](http://code.google.com/p/pyo/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm gonna try what you suggest asap. By the way I'm in good way to handle it, since i had confirmation with playing my raw dump into Audacity again and after some settings, and good earing, i could ear a word. It's a bit messy but this gives me a hint that the data are not encrypted. After your test, i'll try to generate a 1k stereo sine, 1k left sine only, 1k right sine only, those 3 in pcm 44.1k 16b, 32k 16b, a regular mp3 and maybe something else ; i'll play it on the server and capture the bytes to find a pattern

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to guess at a format. First, of all, have a look at the bitrate. How many bytes per second do you get? This will help you calculate whether it might be PCM, or whether it is a compressed format.

You should be able to rule out PCM very easily. Put a bunch of the audio packets into a WAV file with different headers (e.g. 44.1kHz/32kHz,16kHz, 16 bit/8bit, mono/stereo) and see if you hear anything remotely resembling your music.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to guess at compressed formats. MP3 might be worth a go (you can recognize it by seeing if the first four bytes in each packet are a [frame header](http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html)).

You may find it supports a variety of formats, since the documentation seems to suggest you can play to it from Windows Media player. So you could look at the 64 byte header and see what changes when you send files encoded in different formats to it.

Comment: The bitrate is not easy to calculate, the server is sending packets to the client continually for 30s. As far as i can see, it's 896 bytes. I tried to count the number of packets for this duration, the result is always around 4300 packets.

Comment: About mp3, i'm sure it's not since all the bytes from the data part of the packet are changing. I tried to change source of the audio station to something that doesnt output sound (line input with no source plugged in) and all the data bytes changed to 0x00, so i'm sure there's no consistent "frame header" thing

Comment: well that's quite a large amount of data, around 128kB/s which points towards uncompressed PCM. It's not quite enough to be 44.1Khz Stereo 16 bit though. However, it is very close to 32kHz 16 bit stereo. Try writing the captured packets to a WAV file with that format and see if it sounds ok.

Comment: That's exactly what i thought when i saw the size of the dump after 30s of logging : ~3.7MB... I'm gonna try this very soon (couple of hours) and keep you updated of my results.

Comment: Because i had 5mns, i generated an empty 32kHz 16 bits stereo wave file with a 1s silent sound. I thought it may help me to quickly identify the header. I can't see some bytes of the header that look familiar. If you look at the header of wave file (5249 4646 3006 0200 5741 5645 666d 7420 1200 0000 0100 0200 007d 0000 00f4 0100) there is no kind of pattern that are common with the header of the packets i captured (5642 0001 0008 d97f 0000 0000 0540 0010 0001 f93f 034d 9522 0140 ac44 0100 0000)
0400 1000 0000 6461 7461 00f4 0100 0000

Comment: but you wouldn't expect a RIFF header. What might be present is the fmt chunk, which contains a WAVEFORMAT

Comment: So the idea is that the fmt chunck is embedded somewhere in the header of the packet... it looks easy to test. gonna try it !